# Is this a bug in the jquery callback, Or is it supposed to work like this?

Tags: jquery, plugins, callback

Usually callbacks can only callback one value at a time. If you want to callback more than one value you have to use an array.
This I find is the case with jquery functions.

But I have come across something strange, and I am not sure if it is a bug, or an unintended feature.

I am writing a plugin, and I have somehow managed to callback more than one item.
The problem is that I don't know if it is a bug, or not, but it works, and I am worried if I am going to cause myself problems with this.

Ok my plugin is called mydialogue. It is basically an extension of the jquery ui dialogue but some extra stuff that I need.
Ok my plugin starts like this

```
$.fn.mydialogue = function(options,callback,message){
```

I have a callback, and a message variable.

Now usually you would use a callback like this.

```
callback(value);
```

but I have done this

```
callback(value,message);
```

I run my plugin like this

```
$('text').mydialogue({
    title : "Note",
    message : data.Note,
    width : "420",
    maxlength : "200",
    textid : "Condition_update",
    mybuttons : ["Update", "Cancel"]
}, function (callback, message) {
    alert(message);
});
```

It is alerting the message fine, but this looks like I have sent back two values in a callback, but surely it shouldn't work, but strangely it does.

The question is how is the callback sending back two items, and should it?
The other question is, am I going to cause myself problems by doing this, or is the fact that this is working just a fluke or a bug in jquery?

---

I have just got it working with a function now, so no need to send an array back from a function. ok the way I see it now is this. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Whenever you do a callback. like
callback(value,message,toys);

When it comes back the value of callback will always be the first item. eg value

```
so the following code gives me the value
$('text').mydialogue({
    title : "Note",
    message : data.Note,
    width : "420",
    maxlength : "200",
    textid : "Condition_update",
    mybuttons : ["Update", "Cancel"]
}, function (callback, message) {
    alert(callback);
});
```

And any further items I add to the callback I have to add after the callback keyword eg

```
$.fn.mydialogue = function(options,callback,message,toys){
```

and so if I wanted to get these back from the callback I would do

```
$('text').mydialogue({
        title : "Note",
        message : data.Note,
        width : "420",
        maxlength : "200",
        textid : "Condition_update",
        mybuttons : ["Update", "Cancel"]
    }, function (callback, message,toys) {
        alert(callback);
    alert(message);
    alert(toys);
    });
```

Please let me know if this is correct. It takes me a while to understand something. I don't learn as fast as some people do.

---

Ok I am close to understanding this.
The code you typed was this.

```
function myFunction(callback, arg1,arg2){
    // do something interesting here!

    // call the callback function, passing it arguments if you wish
    callback(arg1,arg2)
}
```

And I understand that would work, but I have been more or less doing this.

```
function myFunction(callback, arg1,arg2){
    // do something interesting here!

    // call the callback function, passing it arguments if you wish
var value=10;
    callback(value,arg1,arg2)
}
```

and in my callback I get value variable coming back from the callback, even though I didn't specify it in the function arguments.

For instance if I called the function

```
myfunction(function(callback,arg1,arg2){
alert(callback);
});
```

If I do this I get the value of the value variable when I alert callback, which would be 10 of course. I just wanted to understand why this is happening. I thought I had done something wrong, but it works, but I was worried it if it was working correctly.

I didn't show all my plugin code because I thought it was irrelavent to the question. So I only showed the code that I thought needed to be shown.

---

Yes Jamiec I was getting confused which is why I posted the question in the first place.
So really the word callback in the function name is really just a variable. So in effect can I just do this?

```
function myFunction(value, arg1,arg2){
    // do something interesting here!

    // call the callback function, passing it arguments if you wish
var value=10;
    callback(value,arg1,arg2)
}
```

so the way I see it is, callback() is the command to call back, and anything inside the brackets are just variables.

So I think you have definately answered my question. In other words I have been using it wrong, but luckily my callbacks are working, because I am using the variable name callback. I think I should change these to avoid confusion in the future. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Youve not shown us how you call the callback from inside your plugin. But there is no bug here, I assure you.

Comment: Callbacks are normal functions you can pass any number of params and i don't see where jquery does this its you that calls the callbacks with two params.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The callback is getting two items because you give it two items...?

Comment: the way you call it only has 2 arguments defined not 3. `message` argument in plugin will be undefined. Seems like you might be getting your variable names crossed up. You have an argument named `callback` being passed to the function that is `callback` in the plugin declaration

Comment: With your edit im starting to wonder a) if you understand what a callback is (You have an argument *in* your callback called `callback`) and b) If you're just getting confused between the name of the parameter (`callback`) and the name of the variable you're passing it (`value`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bug here, the arguments to a javascript function are somewhat *fluid* in that I can define a function like this:

```
function aFunction(arg1){...}
```

Yet call it like this:

```
aFunction("someValue",123)
```

With no ill effect - and I can actually access that non-specified argument using the `arguments` array (`arguments[1] // <-- has value 123`).

I can also do this the other way around, I can define a function like this:

```
function bFunction(arg1,arg2){...}
```

Yet call it like this:

```
bFunction("someValue")
```

In this situation, the value of `arg2` is simply `undefined`

---

With regard to your edit, you're seriously misunderstanding what this `callback` is doing, and how it is used.

Forget plugins for a moment, just think javascript. If you define a function like this:

```
function myFunction(callback){..}
```

With the intention to pass a function reference in to callback:

```
//call myFunction, passing a fuunction reference to the first argument
myFunction(function(){..});
```

It does not magically get passed any further arguments you define on the function taking the callback, ie, if you changed that function above to

```
function myFunction(callback, arg1,arg2){..}
```

then the `callback` function will not magically get passed `arg1` & `arg2`! Its how you call the `callback` **yourself** inside the function that matters. If I wanted that to happen, I would need to code it appropriately

```
function myFunction(callback, arg1,arg2){
    // do something interesting here!

    // call the callback function, passing it arguments if you wish
    callback(arg1,arg2)
}
```

The function above could then be called like so

```
myFunction(function(a1,a2){
   // arg1 & arg2 only passed in to this callback because thats how I coded it above
},"valueForArg1","valueForArg2")
```

Hopefully this explains what is going on in your plugin - your extra parameters passed to the function initialising the plugin will *not* automagically get passed back to your callback - its all how you code your plugin. You;ve neither explained what your plugin is trying to do with the callback, nor how you are calling the callback function itself.

Comment: I have just added some more details to my question. So I wonder if anybody can help since I have added some more information

Comment: @ThomasWilliams - I have updated answer, but read the final paragraph if it does not help - you've still not provided the actual infomation needed to give you a concrete answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Jamiec, I have added a little more. I think my inability to ask the question in a clear way, indicates that I need to do a lot more learning before I understand the problem enough to ask the question. What I am doing actually works, but the big thing I was worried about is that, am I doing it correctly or not? I wil give you the upvote though, because I believe you answered as best you can even though I wasn't clear enough.